# Numerus von »die AUA« (die Austrian Airlines)

Tags: grammatical-number

Derzeit wird in österreichischen Medien gerade intensiv über ausgefallene Flüge bei den Austrian Airlines (beachte den Plural!) berichtet. Dabei hört und liest man häufig Sätze dieser Art:

> Ab Dienstag **startet die AUA** mit neuen Diskonttarifen für Österreich.
>   **Die AUA hat** ein sehr dichtes Netz in Osteuropa.
>   **Die AUA musste** 36 Flüge nach und ab Wien streichen.

In diesen Beispielen wird »*AUA*« wie ein weibliches Einzahl-Nomen verwendet, was auch dem tatsächlich üblichen Sprachgebrauch entspricht. »AUA« ist aber die Abkürzung des Plural-Begriffs »**Au**strian **A**irlines« (auf deutsch: »Österreichische Fluglinien«). Und tatsächlich werden in Wort und Schrift die *Austrian Airlines* auch immer im Plural verwendet:

> Ab Dienstag **starten die Austrian Airlines** mit neuen Diskonttarifen für Österreich.
>   **Die Austrian Airlines haben** ein sehr dichtes Netz in Osteuropa.
>   **Die Austrian Airlines mussten** 36 Flüge nach und ab Wien streichen.

Dazu meine Fragen:
- Wie kann es dazu kommen, dass die Abkürzung eines Pluraletantums ein Singularetantum ist?
- Gibt es dafür noch andere Beispiele?
- Gibt es einen Namen für dieses Phänomen?

Comment: Ein anderes prominentes Beispiel: *USA* wird oft als Singular verwendet, *Vereinigte Staaten* jedoch als Plural.

Comment: @Chris: Ich nahe noch nie bemerkt, dass *die USA* wie ein Einzahlwort verwendet würden. Kannst du Beispiele für deine Behauptung anführen?

Comment: Naja, zwar werden Sprachpuristen einwenden, dass *die USA* Plural sein sollte, aber ich hör das schon recht häufig im Singular, v.a. in der Alltagssprache. Beispiele (teilweise auch von Zeitungsauftritten) findet man, wenn man nach "die USA ist" oder "in der USA" googelt.

Comment: In den USA wird “the U.S.” regelmäßig mit Verben im Singular verbunden.

Comment: Die AUA ist eine Gesellschaft oder ein Unternehmen und nicht mehrere, glanz gleich ob im Namen Airlines  im Plural steht oder nicht.

Comment: @rogermue: Wenn dein Argument richtig wäre, würde es ebenso für die Langform gelten, was aber nicht der Fall ist. Niemand sagt oder schreibt »Die *Austrian Airlines **hat*** ein sehr dichtes Netz in Osteuropa.«

Answer (score 2):

Bei AUA schwingt mE immer der volle Firmenwortlaut, Austrian Airlines **AG**, mit, was beim Kurznamen *Austrian Airlines* nicht geht. Prinzipiell gibt es aber wohl eine Tendenz, ein Unternehmen als Einheit zu sehen und im Singular zu bezeichnen. Das war zB bei der VÖEST (... Stahlwerk**e**) auch nicht anders).